# How to choose which application Chrome uses for deep links (e.g. when zoom:823948290348 is typed into Chrome's URI bar)?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, protocol-handler

When I type `zoom:meeting_id=823948290348` into Chrome's url bar, Chrome opens a popup saying "A website wants to open the Zoom application". I then click on the button saying "Open Zoom".

My question is though, I have multiple applications on my computer that can "open" this URI.  How do I tell windows that I don't want to use Zoom but I want to use another application?  Where does Chrome/Windows 10 store which protocols are associated with which applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to change on my computer the application that is used for Zoom
by changing the registry command that launches it:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\zoommtg\shell\open\command`
- Double-click the `(Default)` key, save its current value as backup,
  and change the value to
  `"C:\path\to\your\application.exe" "--url=%1"`

Change the parameter of the above command to suite the application that
you are calling.

(This works in my environment and for my browser.
I have no idea if this will work for you.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what application are you using for opening zoom links? I would have assumed only Zoom would be able to handle those.

Comment: You can use the zoom api (https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/using-zoom-apis) for example to create a custom client etc.